# Saving the text of Textarea before exiting form in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I do:

```
 @Override
    protected void exitMain(Form f) {
        text = findTextArea().getText();
    }
```

but I am not sure `exitMain()` is even called when I move to the other form, so text remains `null`.

How can I catch the value of `textArea` when leaving the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply due to an @`Override` annotation missing before the `initVars()` method.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case

Comment: The override annotation is meaningless in Java

Comment: Yet I thought I witnessed this acted as the decisive factor to get the app to function vs breaking. Puzzled now.